# Install mercusys wifi adapter in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have been trying to install mercusys wifi adpater in ubuntu 16.04. Typing `lsusb` returns:

```
marcos@spac-lia:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2c4e:0100  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0951:1625 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 101 II
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After testing, I could realize that my wifi adapter information corresponds to:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2c4e:0100
```

I have tried to install the drivers with `ndisgtk` but it is not working

Comment: What kernel are you using `uname -a` in terminal

Comment: uname -a
Linux spac-lia 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added your device to my fork of Mange's rtl8192eu-linux-driver on github, in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Reboot

You will have to remove any driver installed with ndisgtk before this will work

Edit I figured out I had a typo

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/1.0 --all
sudo dkms uninstall rtl8192eu/1.0
sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8192eu-1.0
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
git pull
cd
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks for implementation! I installed as suggested, but still not working. lsusb in terminal still returns only Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2c4e:0100 for the device. An wifi icon in nm-applet has appeared, though.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 run the wireless-info script and then do `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` post the URL so I can see some more info.  The `lsusb` results will not change because of a driver but you should see something new in `lshw -c net`

Comment: See the URL:  http://termbin.com/yo4m

Comment: See if it works after `sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper; sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf`  then reboot

Comment: Still not working... Should I also purge ndiswrapper-dkms?  I also ran wireless-info script again. See the URL http://termbin.com/eqqs

Comment: What happens if you `sudo modprobe -v 8192eu`

Comment: It returns: insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko  and insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/8192eu.ko

Comment: What about `modinfo | grep 0100`

Comment: modinfo: ERROR: missing module or filename. Typing only modinfo, returns the same.

Comment: Answer edited to fix typo

Comment: Working perfectly now. Thanks for the great work

Comment: I have tried to install it on a upgraded system: Linux marcos-lia 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, but did not work.  Can you help in fixing it and "adjust for the new kernel"?

Comment: Start a new question

Comment: Question started https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053484/install-mercusys-wifi-adapter-om-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8192eu-linux-drivers