# Install mercusys wifi adapter om Ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8192eu linux drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04

I tried to install a mercusys wifi adpater on ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8192eu linux drivers but has not worked. Below some useful information.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f9:0376 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2c4e:0100  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

uname -a
Linux marcos-lia 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I installed the rtl8192eu linux drivers

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

But it has not worked. How can it be fixed? The outcome of the  [wireless-info script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) can be found [here](http://termbin.com/hq9h)

More information:

```
usb-devices | awk '/2c4e/' RS=

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2c4e ProdID=0100 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek 
S:  Product=802.11n NIC 
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)

sudo modprobe 8192eu
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic

modinfo 8192eu | grep 0100
modinfo: ERROR: Module 8192eu not found.
```

`dkms status` returns

```
rtl8192eu, 1.0, 4.15.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/2c4e/' RS=` terminal command.

Comment: And also post the output of `sudo modprobe 8192eu`.

Comment: Also: `modinfo 8192eu | grep 0100` Possibly helpful: https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/rtl8192eu-forcing-right-driver-to-load/54349/6

Comment: @chili555 The adapter is supported. I bet it is a Secure Boot issue.

Comment: It looks like the driver is not properly installed. Please post output of `dkms status`.

Comment: Try `sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0 -k 4.15.0-23-generic` and reboot