# Install Mercusys MU6H WiFi adapter on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

I am trying to install this adapter on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I tried a method from [Install mercusys wifi adapter in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007792/install-mercusys-wifi-adapter-in-ubuntu)
but I got an error:

```
~/Documents/mercurys/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$ sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.4.0-29-generic........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8192eu: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-29-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build/make.log for more information.
```

And with sudo make:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /home/m4nuelst/Documents/mercurys/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1719: /home/m4nuelst/Documents/mercurys/rtl8192eu-linux-driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1700: modules] Error 2
```

Please, help me. What can I do except returning this to the shop?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: There's no guarantee that yesterday's chipset is in today's adapter. Therefore, we need to confirm which chipset's in _this_ adapter. Please run _sudo lshw -class network -short && sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless' && sudo lsusb -v_  Highlight the resulting text, do Ctrl-Shift-C to copy, then return here, click [edit], and paste the results into your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: [It seems](https://github.com/electrified/asus-wmi-sensors/issues/3#issuecomment-455593733) you will need a fixed driver or wait until kernel 4.17